# angular : reload page after redirection

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-routing, angular-router

I have a function which redirects to another page, I want that after redirection the redirected page also reloads.

***I want to reload the login page after being redirected to it.
using 'window.location.reload()' reloads the current page which is home page but not the login page.
How to reload a specefic page?***

***homeComponent.ts***

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, FormControl, Validators, Form } from '@angular/forms';
import { LoginComponent } from '../authentification/login/login.component';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})



export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
   
  }

  constructor(private router: Router) { }


   redirection(){
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
   }

  
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Why don't u use

```
redirection(){
   window.location.href="yourpagedomain/login"
 }
```

it will load page .

Comment: that works for any component that redirects to login page ? what if I have another component home2 where I want to redirect to login but not reload login ? 
Also can you give me the whole code of the function redirection() for method 1 'window.location.href="your login link" '  ? Thank you in advance friend :)

Comment: then in home2 component you will use this.router.navigate(['/login']);

Answer (score 1):

On your login page you can catch the navigate event, and then if it is true, you can reload you're form. I hope it will help you :

On your login page:

OLD : Wrong code

```
export class LoginPage implements OnInit {
  
  constructor(private router: Router) {
   router.events.subscribe(val => {
      if (val) {
        this.refreshForm(); // Refresh your form
      }
    });
  }
 
  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

}
```

EDIT : this code works :

```
export class LoginPage implements OnInit {

  constructor(private router: Router) {
   router.events.pipe(
      filter((events: RouterEvent) => events instanceof NavigationEnd),
    ).subscribe((val) => {
      if (val.url === 'LoginPage Url') { // Fill with your loginPage Url (eg. /tabs/tab1)
        this.refresh(); // Refresh your form
      }
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
}
```

Comment: where did you catch the redirection function in the code ? didn't get it :/

Comment: router.events.subscribe(val => {
      if (val) {
        this.refreshForm(); // Refresh your form
      }
    });

Comment: that works for any component that redirects to login page ? what if I have another component home2 where I want to redirect to login but not reload login ?

Comment: this will catch the navigation event. If val is true, you can use a function to reset form fields.

Comment: It works only for the page where this code is. ( sorry for my writting english )

Comment: I understand you Bertrand, but if I have another component home2 which has also a navigation event but without reloading the page , in this method  it will reload the page because it catches every navigation event even when there is no need to reload.

Comment: hum i just tested putting a console log inside, and you are right. This method is a wrong way to do that. (and you helped me !) Thanks Firas !

Comment: i updated my answer with a new code ! I tested it on my app and it's fine.